# Why double quote does not work in echo statement inside cmd in awk script?

Tags: awk, base64

```
gawk 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|" }NR ==1 {print} NR >=2 {cmd1="echo -n "$2" | base64 -w 0";cmd1 | getline d1;close(cmd1); print $1,d1 }' dummy2.txt
```

input:

```
id|dummy                                                                           
1|subhashree:1;user=phn                                                             
2|subha:2;user=phn
```

Expected output:

```
id|dummy                                       
1|c3ViaGFzaHJlZToxO3VzZXI9cGhuCg==                               
2|c3ViaGE6Mjt1c2VyPXBobgo=
```

output produced by script:

```
id|dummy                                       
1|subhashree:1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2|subha:2
```

I have understood that the double quote around $2 is causing the issue. It does not work hence not encoding the string properly and just stripping off the string after semi colon.Because it does work inside semicolon and gives proper output in terminal.

```
echo "subhashree:1;user=phn" | base64                                               
c3ViaGFzaHJlZToxO3VzZXI9cGhuCg==                                                         
[root@DERATVIV04 encode]# echo "subha:2;user=phn" | base64                               
c3ViaGE6Mjt1c2VyPXBobgo=
```

I have tried with different variation with single and double quote inside awk but it does not work.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing `cmd1` producing

```
echo -n subhashree:1;user=phn | base64 -w 0

                    ^ semicolon is there
```

So if you execute below would produce

```
$ echo -n subhashree:1;user=phn | base64 -w 0
subhashree:1
```

With quotes

```
$ echo -n 'subhashree:1;user=phn' | base64 -w 0
c3ViaGFzaHJlZToxO3VzZXI9cGhu
```

Solution is just to use quotes before `echo -n '<your-string>' | base64 -w 0`

```
$ cat file 
id|dummy
1|subhashree:1;user=phn
2|subha:2;user=phn

$ gawk -v q="'" 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|" }NR ==1 {print} NR >=2 {cmd1="echo -n " q $2 q" | base64 -w 0";  cmd1 | getline d1;close(cmd1); print $1,d1 }' file
id|dummy
1|c3ViaGFzaHJlZToxO3VzZXI9cGhu
2|c3ViaGE6Mjt1c2VyPXBobg==
```

It can be simplified as below

```
gawk -v q="'" 'BEGIN {
                 FS=OFS="|"
               }
               NR==1{
                  print;
                  next
               }
               {
                 cmd1="echo -n " q $2 q" | base64 -w 0";
                 print ((cmd1 | getline d1)>0)? $1 OFS d1 : $0;
                 close(cmd1);
               }
               ' file
```

Based on [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) recommendation http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

```
if/while ( (getline var < file) > 0)
if/while ( (command | getline var) > 0)
if/while ( (command |& getline var) > 0)
```

Comment: Using a variable to hold the single quote isn't bad but it only works in contexts where you do string concatenation so IMHO you're better off using `\047` everywhere you need `'` as it works in all contexts (`$0 == "\047foo\047"`, `/\047foo\047/`, etc.) and works whether the script is called on the command line or stored in a file (unlike the other common alternative of `'\''`) and doesn't require you to remember to write `-v q="'""` on the command line.

Comment: So `md1="echo -n " q $2 q" | base64 -w 0"` could be written as `md1="echo -n \047" $2 "\047 | base64 -w 0"` and then you can get rid of `-v q="'"`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of lack of quotes, when trying to run the `echo` command in shell context. What you are trying to do is basically converted into

```
echo -n subhashree:1;user=phn | base64 -w 0
```

which the shell has executed as two commands separated by `;` i.e. `user=phn | base64 -w 0`  means an assignment followed by a pipeline, which would be empty because the assignment would not produce any result over standard input for `base64` for encode. The other segment `subhashree:1` is just echoed out, which is stored in your `getline` variable `d1`.

The right approach fixing your problem should be using quotes

```
echo -n "subhashree:1;user=phn" | base64 -w 0
```

When you said, you were using quotes to `$2`, that is not actually right, the quotes are actually used in the context of `awk` to concatenate the `cmd` string i.e. `"echo -n "`, `$2` and `" | base64 -w 0"` are just joined together. The proposed double quotes need to be in the context of the shell.

SO with that and few other fixes, your `awk` command should be below. Added `gsub()` to remove trailing spaces, which were present in your input shown. Also used `printf` over echo.

```
awk -v FS="|" '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = FS
    }
    
    NR == 1 {
        print
    }
    
    NR >= 2 {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, "", $2)
        cmd = "printf \"%s\" \"" $2 "\" | base64 -w 0"
        if ((cmd | getline result) > 0) {
            $2 = result
        }
        close(cmd)
        print
    }    
' file
```

So with the command above, your command is executed as below, which would produce the right result.

```
printf "%s" "subhashree:1;user=phn" | base64 -w 0
```

Comment: Nice - exactly the right syntax for the call to getline and use of it's result.

Answer (score 2):

You already got answers explaining how to use awk for this but you should also consider not using awk for this. The tool to sequence calls to other commands (e.g. `bas64`) is a shell, not awk. What you're trying to do in terms of calls is:

```
shell { awk { loop_on_input { shell { base64 } } } }
```

whereas if you call `base64` directly from shell it'd just be:

```
shell { loop_on_input { base64 } }
```

Note that the awk command is spawning a new subshell once per line of input while the direct call from shell isn't.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file='dummy2.txt'
head -n 1 "$file"
while IFS='|' read -r id dummy; do
    printf '%s|%s\n' "$id" "$(base64 -w 0 <<<"$dummy")"
done < <(tail -n +2 "$file")
```

Here's the difference in execution speed for an input file that has each of your data lines duplicated 100 times created by `awk -v n=100 'NR==1{print; next} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print}' dummy2.txt > file100`

```
$ ./tst.sh file100
Awk:

real    0m23.247s
user    0m3.755s
sys     0m10.966s

Shell:

real    0m14.512s
user    0m1.530s
sys     0m4.776s
```

The above timing was produced by running this command (both awk scripts posted in answers will have about the same timeing so I just picked one at random):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doawk() {
    local file="$1"
    gawk -v q="'" 'BEGIN {
                 FS=OFS="|"
               }
               NR==1{
                  print;
                  next
               }
               {
                 cmd1="echo -n " q $2 q" | base64 -w 0";
                 print ((cmd1 | getline d1)>0)? $1 OFS d1 : $0;
                 close(cmd1);
               }
               ' "$file"
}

doshell() {
    local file="$1"
    head -n 1 "$file"
    while IFS='|' read -r id dummy; do
        printf '%s|%s\n' "$id" "$(base64 -w 0 <<<"$dummy")"
    done < <(tail -n +2 "$file")
}

# Use 3rd-run timing to eliminate cache-ing as a factor

doawk "$1" >/dev/null
doawk "$1" >/dev/null
echo "Awk:"
time doawk "$1" >/dev/null

echo ""

doshell "$1" >/dev/null
doshell "$1" >/dev/null
echo "Shell:"
time doshell "$1" >/dev/null
```

Comment: Hi Ed Morton...I understand your point completely and also I have a solution for bash as well but the point is I need to use awk here for my usecase as I hv to use the output of other awk commands to this base64 usecase...hence I hv done all the solution in awk as I hv to deal with multiple columns of CSV file to perform different operations...but Thanks a lot for the explanation it is really useful...will definitely try it out incase I am allowed to...

Comment: @SubhashreeBehera no, you don't have to do this in awk, you could simply pipe the output of this to awk or vice-versa. If you don't care about the efficiency then calling an external command for 1 field from awk for is fine though as long as you get the syntax right which both awk answers now do.